# Migrating access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I've been asked to supervise the migration from an MS Access database to SQL Server. The tool being used is SSMA for Access.

During the progress we have been facing an issue

> Synchronization Error: The foreign key cascading '[table name]' can not be created where the column reference '[table name].Codigo' is an identity column.

Is there any way to solve this without altering the structure of the table? We are facing this problem on multiple tables and it'd take ages to change the structure of the all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check access database if the foreign key column used in the given table has also been setup as a primary key. This would suggest the table (a child table) is a one to one relationship to the parent table. If the FK column was (or was converted) to a PK column then that column would be both a FK and PK column at the same time. I would also try upsizing to a new SQL database in place of overwriting data in existing (if that is your case). You can/should remove the PK setting on that FK column if you discover this to be the case (add a autonumber ID column to that table to replace the bad PK).

Answer (score 0):

You could shut off the identity checking by

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table name] ON
```

Do your insert into SQL and then

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table name] OFF
```

Comment: SSMA is creating the tables and pushing up the data. Dropping SSMA, means up-sizing process becomes un-practical manual process. Not clear if the error message is due to PK inserts, or SSMA attempting to create a child table in which the FK is both a FK and a PK column at the same time. SSMA does allow one to add "custom" SQL commands for a given table, so I will state that allowing PK inserts might fix this, but as such, the identity insert has to be added to SSMA (sql migration assistant) since SSMA usually is migrating more than one table of related data (else why use SSMA for 1 table?).